# ホームページの「お礼」タブを常時表示させておきたい

Tags: 機能の要求

### 前提

スタック・オーバーフローでは[ホームページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com)に幾つかのタブがあり、そこには

- 最近投稿された、回答された、または更新された質問
- 過去 2 日間の閲覧数、回答数、および得票数が最多の質問
- 今週の閲覧数、回答数、および得票数が最多の質問
- 今月の閲覧数、回答数、および得票数が最多の質問

の四つのタブが表示されています。しかし、実際には「お礼」というタブも存在し、これは**お礼が付与された質問が存在しない場合は非表示**にされています。このタブは直接「[お礼」タブの URL](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured) へアクセスすることで閲覧することが出来、お礼が付与されている質問がないことを示すページが表示されます。

---

### 提案

お礼が付与されていない状態でも「お礼」タブが表示されるようにすることを提案します。

特定の条件で「お礼」タブを隠した場合、タブが消えたことはわかりますが、お礼が付与された質問が存在しないことはわかりません。そのため、これはユーザーを混乱させる可能性があり、お礼が付与された質問が存在しない場合にも表示しておいたほうが良いと思います。

Answer (score 1):

私は現状の仕様、"アクティブなお礼質問が無ければ非表示" のままで十分だと思います。

常に表示とした場合、特に「お礼」という仕組みにまだ詳しくないユーザーがこのタブに切り替えても、結局何も表示されないだけなのであまり親切とは思えません。
(出来たてのホームページでリンクをクリックしても、リンク先のページが"工事中"とだけ書かれているばかりでがっかりした経験と似ています)

表示される要素の増減によってデザインが崩れる、などの問題がない限りは今のままで十分かと。